# User list and roles integration

Tags: java, design

I work for a brand new start-up who wants to roll out a product. One of the task for me is to integrate the existing user and role details of the client company and integrate it with our company dashboard. Our dashboard is simply designed with java. Now different client companies might have different ways of storing user information like, Active Directory, Azure cloud, simple Oauth 2.0 or just username password based access. Is it possible for me to design a one size fit for all solution? How do experienced people deal with this kind of issues? please let me know some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good questions to ask:

Who's setting the roles? Our company or the client company?

Can we get examples to work from? Active Directory etc...

I'd make a plugin for each user info data store that adapts whatever it finds into a common data structure that our dashboard knows how to use.

So long as client companies put the data you need in the same place on every different product this isn't that complicated. If they don't... Ow.

Comment: Roles are set by the client company. Like you said we have to design a plugin which can pool information from their employee database. Their company admin can assign user roles for using our software. Since we do not have customers yet, no practical examples either...